# Embedded scripting engine in a .NET application

Tags: c#, scripting, editor, embed, winwrap

I am looking to replace an old control being used for scripting an application.  The control used to be called SAX Basic, but is now called [WinWrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinWrap_Basic). It provides us with two primary functions.

1. It's a scripting engine (VB)
2. It has a GUI for developing and debugging scripts that get run in the hosting application.

The first feature it provides is actually pretty easy to replace.  There are so many great methods of running just about any kind of code at runtime that it's almost a non-issue.  Just about any language targeting the .NET runtime will work for us.  We've looked at running C#, PowerShell, VB.NET, IronPython, etc.  I've also taken a brief look at Lua and F#, but honestly the language isn't the biggest barrier here.

Now, for the hard part that seems to keep getting me stuck.  We want a code editor, and debugger.  Something simple, not unlike PowerShell's ISE would be fine.  Just as long as a file could be created, saved, debugged and executed.

I'm currently looking into Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) and I'm also looking at the feasibility of embedding [PowerShell ISE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell#PowerShell_2.0) in my application.  Are there any other editors I could embed/use in my application?  Purchasing a product is not out of the question.  It comes down to a combination of ease of use, how well it meets our needs, and how simple deployment and licensing is for developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I have not used this solution myself, I would recommend that you look into [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) (OSS .NET IDE) - it has text editor controls that have been embedded in other applications, for instance [Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/).

Comment: Looked into it briefly.  It wasn't real clear on how to use their editor controls.  Maybe I'll revisit it.  Thanks.

Comment: A co-worker has been working on this recently.  It is working very well.  I am surprised SharpDevelop has not advertised this capability more.  This solution has turned out to be ideal.